# Multiple database implementation in django

Tags: django, django-models, multiple-databases

I have two databases, which I need to use in the same app of django asynchronously.

I have referred following document :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/
which basically tells the configuration of DATABASE_ROUTERS but doesn't really explain how to use methods like db_for_read, db_for_write, etc in views.py let's say.

Can someone help me out in configuring tables from different databases(not synchronous to each other) in the same app.

Thanks!

Comment: It should return the name of the database to read from/write to (so a string).

Comment: See the [*example* section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example).

Comment: In the link mentioned above, if you scroll down, you'll see examples how the models are saved automatically in the correct database using the routing defined. But it also shows how to select a db manually for saving and/or deleting. You don't call the methods `db_for_read` and `db_for_write` yourself.